# Django-Upload image to MySQL Database as BLOB

Tags: python, mysql, django

Im creating an E-shop and i have an admin dashboard where i add new products in database. Currently im storing directly the product image as file, and phpmyadmin is converting it to `BLOB`. But this is not an efficient way to do this. So im coding a HTML page where i can send the image to backend and then upload it to the database.

Im using Django Forms to register a new product as follows

Forms.py

```
class Upload_New_Product_Form(forms.Form):
    product_id = forms.IntegerField()
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

products.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'upload_new_product' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="input-group">
     {{product_form}}
     </div>
     <br>
      <button type="submit" class="makeChangebtn btn-primary">Submit changes</button>
 </form>
```

views.py

```
def Upload_New_Product_View(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        _id = request.POST['product_id']
        name = request.POST['name']
        price = request.POST['price']
        image = request.POST['image']
        print(image)
        new_product = Product.objects.create(id=_id,name=name,price=price,image=image)
        new_product.save()
```

When i print the image in my views.py from `POST` request, i get only the name of the image. **What is the correct way to retrieve the image and then convert it in binary to finally store it on database?**

Comment: It is best to store files as a file and not in the database. Also look at [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) which is what you want. Also Files are in `request.FILES` instead of `request.POST`. Also you need to set a few more attributes on your form tag so it may post file data namely `enctype="multipart/form-data"`